# A backdrop remained there even after closing the sweetalert2 making the div element unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

I have create a sweet alert from jquery whenever an error occurs. And the sweetalert2 code for this looks as follows:

```
Swal.fire({
        title: 'Sorry!',
        text: "We couldn't find what you are looking. Let us know, so that we could add the feature in near future. ",
        type: 'error',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Ok!',
        confirmButtonColor: "#21b9bb",
        cancelButtonText: 'Let it Go!',
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            window.open(
                base_path+'/contact/request-feature',
                '_blank'
            );
        } else if (
            // Read more about handling dismissals
            result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
        ) {
            Swal.fire(
                'Find Another Rink',
                'Please, try with different search parameter.'
            )
        }
    })
```

But, even after clicking either button mentioned here a backdrop still remaining there which can be viewed by inspecting the element as follows:

[image: Screenshot]

Because of this, the calendar becomes unclickable.

How can I get rid of this, So that I can click on the div which is covered by this div.

Comment: You have to toggle CSS for show/hide alert. add `visibility: hidden; opacity: 0` CSS in highlighted `div` when alertbox is closed.

Comment: based on which element?